# Converting jOOQ record to POJO using converter

Tags: java, pojo, jooq

In my Oracle database, I have amount values which are stored as VARCHAR. When retrieving records from the database, I wish to map them to a POJO in which the amount values are represented as double. Unfortunately, I cannot use forced types as in the database everything is stored as VARCHAR and there is no pattern which identify a column as one which contains an amount value.

I was taking a look at the [jOOQ converters](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.11/manual/sql-execution/fetching/data-type-conversion/) which seem to be what I want. Therefore, I created a jOOQ converter for this purpose:

```
public class DoubleConverter implements Converter<String, Double> {

    @Override
    public Double from(String stringValue) {
        return new Double(stringValue);
    }

    @Override
    public String to(Double doubleValue) {
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
        df.setMinimumFractionDigits(0);
        df.setGroupingUsed(false);

        return df.format(doubleValue);
    }

    @Override
    public Class<String> fromType() {
        return String.class;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<Double> toType() {
        return Double.class;
    }

}
```

However, I want to trigger this converter whenever I want to map the database record to my POJO using `record.into(MyClass.class)` and then trigger back whenever I am writing back to the database. How do you recommend to achieve this please?

Comment: *"Unfortunately, I cannot use forced types as in the database everything is stored as VARCHAR."* - This doesn't really explain why you cannot use forced types. The forced type code generation configuration is exactly made for the purpose you have in mind. Would you mind explaining what you were struggling with in this area?

Comment: Hi, Lukas. I meant that every value (whether numeric or text) is stored as VARCHAR in the database that I am working with. Therefore, I cannot use forced types since I cannot convert all VARCHAR columns to double and using expressions since there is no pattern about which columns are numeric. Therefore, that is why I wish to achieve this as explained in the question.

Comment: Well, how else would jOOQ know when to apply your converter unless you tell it to? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I strongly suggest you somehow get a list of all double columns and a apply a forced type configuration in your code generation configuration, in your particular case, you do not have to do much in order to be able to call `record.into(MyClass.class)`.

Your `record` will contain only `String` values and your `MyClass` class will contain matching `double` attributes. jOOQ will auto-convert from `String` to `double` and vice versa. By default, the [`DefaultRecordMapper`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DefaultRecordMapper.html) and [`DefaultRecordUnmapper`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DefaultRecordUnmapper.html) will be applied.

You can override those by specifying a new `RecordMapperProvider` and a `RecordUnmapperProvider` as is documented here:
https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/fetching/pojos-with-recordmapper-provider

It will be a bit of work to do that properly.